# A property of a bounded set

Tags: general-topology

Prove that is $A$ is bounded, then the least upper bound of $A$ is in $A$ or a point of accumulation.

proof: Let $A$ be a bounded set and $x\in A$. Then, since $A$ is bounded there exists an $M\in\mathbb{R}$, without loss of generality let $x \geq M$, then x is an lower bound of $A$.

I am pretty lost with this proof, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear.

Comment: I know but this is the question my professor gave us: Show that if A is a bounded set then l.u.b.(A) is an element of A or a point of accumulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ is a non empty subset of $\Bbb R$, $A$ has a supremum $x$.

If $x\notin A$, take any $\delta>0$. If $A\cap (x-\delta, x+\frac\delta2)$ is empty, then $x-\frac\delta2$ is an upper bound for $A$, and it is lesser than $x$.

Comment: Not following your reasoning, could you explain further?

Comment: What is your definition for 'point of accumulation'?